# Prevent compiler from considering implicitly-declared copy constructor in C++03

Tags: c++

Note that I am working in C++03, and the `delete`d functions of C++11 are not available to me.

I am attempting to design a non-copyable object, and prevent the compiler from considering the implicitly-declared copy constructor on that class.  This is for a unit test fixture I am developing.

Consider that I have two main objects: a core library object, `Root`, and a derived special-case object under test, `Branch`.  I am trying to develop a test fixture class, `Fixture` which handles the minutiae of setting up & talking to the core `Root` object.  So this is a simplified illustration of what I've built so far:

([Here is an ideone link](http://ideone.com/TTE4qt) with the same code below, except I've defined my own `noncopyable`)

```
#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>

class Root
{
};

class Fixture
:
    public boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    Fixture (Root& root)
    :
        mRoot (root)
    {
    }
private:
    Root& mRoot;
};

class Branch
:
    public Root,
    public Fixture
{
public:
    Branch()
    :
        Fixture (*this)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Branch branch;
}
```

Compiling this results in:

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘Branch::Branch()’:
main.cpp:30:23: error: call of overloaded ‘Fixture(Branch&)’ is ambiguous
main.cpp:30:23: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:13:5: note: Fixture::Fixture(Root&)
main.cpp:8:7: note: Fixture::Fixture(const Fixture&)
```

It is not possible* to prevent the C++03 compiler from implicitly declaring a copy constructor for `Fixture` unless I declare at least one on my own.  But even with:

```
class Fixture
:
    public boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    Fixture (Root& root)
    :
        mRoot (root)
    {
    }
private:
    Fixture (const Fixture&);
    Fixture (Fixture&);
    Root& mRoot;
};
```

...the compiler will still consider these `private` declarations when initializing `Fixture` in `Branch`'s initialization list:

```
Fixture (*this)
```

I want the compiler to simply not consider these copy constructors.

I could do this by doing a little contorting on my own:

```
Fixture (static_cast <Root&> (*this))
```

...but I'd rather not, as it's a bit smelly to my nose and non-copy-ability is the *semantics* of what I'm going for by deriving `Fixture` from `boost::noncopyable`.

Is there a way to prevent the compiler from considering implicitly-declared copy constructors in this case without changing code at the call-site from:

```
Fixture (*this)
```

?

---

- "It is not possible..." : Standard C++03: 12.8/4, "Special member functions":

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy
>   constructor, one is declared implicitly.

Comment: Would deleted functions in C++11 even help? Deleted functions still participate in overload resolution.

Comment: @KerrekSB:  Honestly, I don't know.  If you're right that they participate in resolution, then I think they wouldn't help.

Comment: I believe a [templated constructor](http://ideone.com/nHhzEi) should take precedence unambiguously...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Aha.  Your sample uses C++11, but I can work with that.

Comment: There are corresponding traits in Boost...

Comment: @KerrekSB:  It does work. http://ideone.com/SA4hUQ  Post it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @KerrekSB You sure that's right? See [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=80720d94d16c1b63cf16cd3580db7da0-c59112800dca6ae4674520521ddfe536)

Comment: @JohnDibling I think your version works, but I guess the SFINAE of Kerrek SB doesn't in the way it's intended to (copy-ctor is called).

Comment: @KerrekSB Perhaps something [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=dda0d6b8de513c5374958d1d93aa1249-c59112800dca6ae4674520521ddfe536)?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Your simple template is too promiscuous. It would make traits like `is_constructible<Fixture, int>` true even though it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ambiguity is that `*this` can bind to both a `Root &` and a `Fixture &`, and both conversions are equally good (namely derived-to-base conversions).

The trick is to create an overload that's a *better* match. For example,

```
template <typename T> Fixture(T &)
```

is will match any lvalue *exactly*, and thus is a better match than an overload that requires a conversion.

However, this is too naive, since you don't actually want your `Fixture` to be constructible from just any­thing. Rather you want it to be constructible only from something that's derived from `Root`. We can disable the extraneous constructors with some SFINAE magic. First the C++11 version:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Root, T>::value>::type>
Fixture(T & x)
: mRoot(x)
{ }
```

In C++03, we use Boost, and we can't use default template arguments:

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template <typename T>
Fixture(T & x,
        typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_base_of<Root, T> >::type * = NULL)
: mRoot(x)
{ }
```

Now you are guaranteed that `T` is derived from `Root`. The overload of this templated constructor with `T = Branch` is an exact match, better than the copy constructor, and so it is selected as the best overload unambiguously.

Comment: With that `enable_if`, this overload is no longer viable for a `Branch &`.  Maybe `is_convertible<T&, Root&>`.

Comment: I can't help but think the SFINAE magic is a bit overboard here.  Afgter all, with a simple `template` constructor (non-SFINAE), if I pass it something that's not convertible (say a `FooBar`), it's just going to fail to compile anyway.

Comment: This obviously won't work because `is_same` won't compile in this scenario, and as I said, I'm using C++03.  I'll fix it.

Comment: @JohnDibling: You absolutely need SFINAE if you don't want to pollute your class with constructors. Overload resolution doesn't care whether the body will compile. You need to remove unwanted overloads right from the outset.

Comment: @DyP: You're absolutely right. I had only checked that it compiles, and not that the right constructor was chosen! :-S I've replaced the trait with `is_base_of`, which should do the right thing.

Comment: Some revisions ago you used `is_convertible`. Though I think `is_base_of` is fine, why did you change that?

Comment: @DyP: I never did. Someone else edited the post. I think `is_base_of` is more appropriate for the situation, but feel free to use whichever suits you best.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to prevent the existence of the copy constructor signature, not in C++98, and not in C++11 either. `= delete` does not remove something from the overload set either, it only fails if it is selected.

I have no better idea than to insert the explicit cast if you don't want to mess with the public interface of Fixture.

Options that do mess with the interface include passing the `Root` by pointer to distinguish from the reference of the copy constructor and passing a tag for the sake of overload resolution. Leave a comment if you want to know more about these.

Comment: +1 I could pass a pointer, but I'd rather pass a reference as I'll be storing a reference.  And if I change the ctor to take a pointer then I'll have to change the call-site code anyway, so I think I'd prefer the `static_cast` in that case.

Comment: Btw, I'm happy to mess with the `public` interface of `Fixture` so long as I don't change the call-site code in `Branch`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to pass around `Branch` as an instance of `Fixture`, there is no need for inheriting it at all. What you basically would like to do is be able to set something up in `Fixture` for all instances of `Root`, if I'm not mistaken. So lets attack that cause, instead of bending C++. **DISCLAIMER**: If it's otherwise, I've no suggestions, I'm afraid.

For this problem, I'd make `Branch` have an instance of `Fixture` as it's member and overload copy-constructor of `Branch` to create the instance of `Fixture` by passing itself as the instance to `Fixture`'s constructor and assignment operator to never copy `Fixture` instance. A brief example is shown below:

```
#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>

class Root
{
};

class Fixture
:
    public boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    Fixture (Root& root)
    :
        mRoot (root)
    {
    }
private:
    Root& mRoot;
};

class Branch
:
    public Root
{
public:
    Branch()
    : mFixture(*this)
    {
    }

    Branch(const Branch& branch)
    : Root(*this)
    , mFixture(*this)
    /* other 'Branch' members to be copied */
    {
    }

    Branch& operator = (const Branch& branch)
    {
        Root::operator=(branch);
        /* copy other 'Branch' members, except 'mFixture' */
    }

    Fixture& getFixture()
    {
        return mFixture;
    }

    const Fixture& getFixture() const
    {
        return mFixture;
    }

private:
    Fixture mFixture;
};
```